# Acts as taggable on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

How can I make an index route/action to see all the tags that I've created!, I'm using the gem at https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

Thanks.

Comment: have I answered what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all to list all the tags, for example

```
# tags_controller.rb
def index
  @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
end

# tags/index.html.erb
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
  some html to display
<% end %>
```

Of course if you don't have a tags controller you will have to create one, and the routes in routes.rb. You can use the rails generate controller tags index command if you want. Run rake routes to see what the routes are.

You can take a look at the actual Tag model here: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/tag.rb
And the fields available for Tag you can find in your db/schema.rb file.